# Nav Bar Sub-Menu not centered

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with drop down sub-menus.  A div is used to center the page on the screen.  When the drop-down menu is shown - it is displaying outside of the div I wanted to constrain my page to.  I can't center the drop down menu.

I've attached a jsfiddle to show the issue  https://jsfiddle.net/JHinkle/n4crd619/18/

Hover over menu "Output" or "Misc" and see the menubar move to the far left side of the screen instead of being left aligned with the left side of the nav bar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hinks_Config</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js" charset="UTF-8">
</script><script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="IEcontent">
<div class="content">

     <div class="navbar">

         <a href="index.htm" >Status</a>     

       <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">Network Config <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
         <a href="Network.htm">Wired / Ethernet</a>                   
         <a href="WIFI.htm">Wireless / WIFI</a>
         </div>
       </div> 

         <a href="E131.htm" >E131 / Artnet</a>

       <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">Output Settings <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
         <a id="PC1" href="PortConfig_1.htm">String Ports 1 - 16</a>                      
         <a id="PC2" href="PortConfig_2.htm">String Ports 17 - 32</a>
         <a id="PC3" href="PortConfig_3.htm">String Ports 33 - 48</a>
         <a href="DMX.htm">DMX / RS485</a>                  
         </div>
       </div> 

       <div class="subnav">
         <button class="subnavbtn">Misc Settings <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
         <div class="subnav-content">
         <a href="FM.htm">FM Transmitter</a>
         <a href="Mode.htm">Operating Mode</a>
         <a href="Time.htm">Time</a>                    
         <a href="Firmware.htm">Active Firmware</a>
         <a href="Debug.htm">Technical</a>
         </div>
       </div>

         <a href="Test.htm" >Test</a>
         <a href="Reset.htm" >Activate Changes</a>


     </div>
    <br />




</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
div.content 
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

div.IEcontent 
{
   text-align: center;
}


legend {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr:hover {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}

.highlighted {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: #E5C37E;
}


.active_RED {
    color: #261F1D;
    background-color: yellow;
}

table 
{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
 }

th 
{
    height: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
   background-color: yellow;

}


table, td , th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

td 
{
    text-align: center;
    height: 15px;
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space: pre;
}



.controlgroup-textinput{
    padding-top: .10em;
    padding-bottom: .10em;
}


.containing-element .ui-slider-switch { width: 10em !important; }



body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
    width: 960px;

}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.subnav {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subnav .subnavbtn 
{
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


.subnav-content a 
{
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn 
{
  background-color: red;

}

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  width: inherit;
   z-index: 1;
}


.subnav-content a:hover 
{
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type=text_Width] {
  width: 10%;
}

input.button_Joe1
{
     width: 15%;
}

.clear
{
    clear: both;
  }

.inlineinput div 
{
    display: inline;
}

#SmartDiff_Table1
{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#SmartDiff_Table2
{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

#SmartDiff_Table3
{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 15%;

}
#SmartDiff_Table4
{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 15%;

}

.btnmainPOS
{
  background-color: #AAFFAA;
}

.btnmainMINUS
{
  background-color: #FF8080;
}
```

Comment: That's because you set .subnav-content left: 0. Try removing that property.

Answer (score 0):

just add style position : relative to div.content

```
div.content 
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hinks_Config</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Project.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        div.content {
            width: 960px;
            margin: auto;
        }

        div.IEcontent {
            text-align: center;
        }

        legend {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        tr:hover {
            color: #261F1D;
            background-color: #E5C37E;
        }

        .highlighted {
            color: #261F1D;
            background-color: #E5C37E;
        }

        .active_RED {
            color: #261F1D;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        th {
            height: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        td {
            text-align: center;
            height: 15px;
            font-size: 10px;
            white-space: pre;
        }

        .controlgroup-textinput {
            padding-top: .10em;
            padding-bottom: .10em;
        }

        .containing-element .ui-slider-switch {
            width: 10em !important;
        }

        body {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
            width: 960px;
        }

        .navbar a {
            float: left;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .subnav {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .subnav .subnavbtn {
            font-size: 16px;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .subnav-content a {
            float: left;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }

        .navbar a:hover,
        .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .subnav-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            float: left;
            background-color: red;
            width: 143px;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .subnav-content a:hover {
            background-color: #eee;
            color: black;
        }

        .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
            display: block;
        }

        input[type=text_Width] {
            width: 10%;
        }

        input.button_Joe1 {
            width: 15%;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

        .inlineinput div {
            display: inline;
        }

        #SmartDiff_Table1 {
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        #SmartDiff_Table2 {
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        #SmartDiff_Table3 {
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        #SmartDiff_Table4 {
            width: 30%;
            margin-left: 15%;
        }

        .btnmainPOS {
            background-color: #AAFFAA;
        }

        .btnmainMINUS {
            background-color: #FF8080;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="IEcontent">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="index.htm">Status</a>
                <div class="subnav">
                    <button class="subnavbtn">Network Config <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="subnav-content">
                        <a href="Network.htm">Wired / Ethernet</a>
                        <a href="WIFI.htm">Wireless / WIFI</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="E131.htm">E131 / Artnet</a>
                <div class="subnav">
                    <button class="subnavbtn">Output Settings <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="subnav-content">
                        <a id="PC1" href="PortConfig_1.htm">String Ports 1 - 16</a>
                        <a id="PC2" href="PortConfig_2.htm">String Ports 17 - 32</a>
                        <a id="PC3" href="PortConfig_3.htm">String Ports 33 - 48</a>
                        <a href="DMX.htm">DMX / RS485</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="subnav">
                    <button class="subnavbtn">Misc Settings <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                    <div class="subnav-content">
                        <a href="FM.htm">FM Transmitter</a>
                        <a href="Mode.htm">Operating Mode</a>
                        <a href="Time.htm">Time</a>
                        <a href="Firmware.htm">Active Firmware</a>
                        <a href="Debug.htm">Technical</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="Test.htm">Test</a>
                <a href="Reset.htm">Activate Changes</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/FD126C42-EBFA-4E12-B309-BB3FDD723AC1/main.js" charset="UTF-8">
    </script>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```